Is my Azure Function still using .NET 6 after upgrading to .NET 8?
I've recently upgraded an Azure Function from .NET 6 to .NET 8. I updated the target framework in my project files and ensured the deployment settings were updated for .NET 8. However, when I log into the Kudu environment and run dotnet --info, it still shows the runtime version as .NET 6:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.x.xx
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.x.xx

Steps taken:

Updated Target Framework: changed the .csproj file to target net8.0
Configuration in Azure Portal: set the stack version to .NET 8 (LTS) under Configuration → General Settings.

Observations:
The function app runs correctly, but the runtime version in Kudu does not reflect .NET 8.
Questions:

Why does the runtime in the Kudu environment still show .NET 6 instead of .NET 8?
How can I confirm that my Azure Function is actually running on .NET 8 in the cloud?
Are there additional steps required to fully upgrade Azure Functions to .NET 8?

Any guidance on how to resolve this mismatch would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Can you show the full output from "dotnet --info". I have an Azure Function that was upgraded from .NET 6 to .NET 8 some time ago and I don't recall there being any unexpected changes required. Kudu is showing the .NET SDK version as 8.0.400 for me.

@user12599720 Check the runtime in your Azure Function by logging System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription. Ensure FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION is set to ~4 and restart the Function App to apply changes.

@user12599720 Can you share your function code and csproj in the question?

@user12599720 Is the .NET 8 model an isolated process or in-process model?

@jmcihinney,  this is on linux global.json file:
Not found
Host:
Version:      6.0.35
Architecture: x64
.NET SDKs installed:
No SDKs were found.
.NET runtimes installed:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.35 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.35 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

@DasariKamali, We are running an in-process model that running in a linux application service plan, and unfortunately I cannot share the source code. The parts that stick out in the csproj file is the target framework is net8 and the function version is 4.


How can I confirm that my Azure Function is actually running on .NET 8 in the cloud?

As per the Doc, .NET 6 has reached its end of support, and any applications targeting .NET 6 are recommended to upgrade to .NET 8.

As .NET 6 has reached it's end of support, your application will work only on .NET 8. In your case the issue might be cached data or old configuration settings that haven't been fully refreshed that showing .NET 6 version.

Clearing old deployment artifacts might resolve your issue. Try deleting the bin and obj folders from your Function App project, then redeploy the application.


When we run the dotnet --info command in the Kudu console of an Azure Function App, it will provide all the runtime versions and installed SDK's in the function app environment.
dotnet --info



It is better to create a new Azure Function App in .NET 8 and deploy your application, as this will help avoid further issues.
